# Using function arguments in a Coldfusion thread

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, cfthread

How can I use function arguments in a Coldfusion thread?
I do not understand why I get the following error:

> Element SOMEID is undefined in ARGUMENTS.

A simplified example of my code.

```
public any function createSomeEntity(required numeric someId) {     
    thread action="run" name="someThread" {
        var result = someFunction(someId = arguments.someId);
        // some logic
    }
    thread action="join" name="someThread" timeout="5000";
    
    if (someThread.status != "COMPLETED") {
        // action 1
    } else {
        // action 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the variable as attribute for to the thread, thread cannot access the argument scope.

```
thread
    action="run"
    name="someThread"
    someId = arguments.someId
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    result = someFunction(someId = attributes.someId);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
    // some logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why, but I didn't find this in CF documentation.

Comment: Could you please answer another question, please? How can I use the result variables in // action 1 section?

Comment: Just ignore my last question, I found the answer to it here - https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-coldfusion-threads/using-thread-data.html
I should use Thread scope (`Thread.result`) instead of var and then call the variable as `someThread.result`